# jQuery not working in Rails 6 with Webpacker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a navbar with an hover dropdown, if i use directly the script in the view its works, if i use it from an external .js file its not working, can someone help and tell me why?

index.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="logo horizontal-logo" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/162656/horizontal-logo.svg" alt="forecastr logo">
      </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

navbar.js

```
const $dropdown = $(".dropdown");
const $dropdownToggle = $(".dropdown-toggle");
const $dropdownMenu = $(".dropdown-menu");
const showClass = "show";
 
$(window).on("load resize", function() {
  if (this.matchMedia("(min-width: 768px)").matches) {
    $dropdown.hover(
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.addClass(showClass);
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "true");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).addClass(showClass);
      },
      function() {
        const $this = $(this);
        $this.removeClass(showClass);
        $this.find($dropdownToggle).attr("aria-expanded", "false");
        $this.find($dropdownMenu).removeClass(showClass);
      }
    );
  } else {
    $dropdown.off("mouseenter mouseleave");
  }
});
```

scss

```
body {
    background: #f2f2f2;
  }
  
  .navbar .nav-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 35px;
  }
  
  .dropdown-toggle::after {
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s linear;
     transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s linear;
     transition: transform 0.15s linear;
     transition: transform 0.15s linear, -webkit-transform 0.15s linear; 
  }
  
  .show.dropdown .dropdown-toggle::after {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
            transform: translateY(3px);
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
```

i have the navbar.js file next to application.js in the route app/javascript/packs/ with an `import './navbar'` and its loading fine.

webpack-dev-server

````
                                     Asset       Size       Chunks                         Chunk Names
    js/application-1d42cea18344d603ac85.js    3.9 MiB  application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
js/application-1d42cea18344d603ac85.js.map   3.88 MiB  application  [emitted] [dev]        application
         js/navbar-3864d86b5f6b24d81913.js    798 KiB       navbar  [emitted] [immutable]  navbar
     js/navbar-3864d86b5f6b24d81913.js.map    830 KiB       navbar  [emitted] [dev]        navbar
                             manifest.json  668 bytes               [emitted]
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.```
````

Comment: How are you loading this js in the view? Is it in application.html.erb?

Comment: @JuJoDi i have the js pack tag `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`

Comment: do you need to include `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'navbar'...%>?`

Comment: @JuJoDi i am calling it from my application.js with `import './navbar'`, anyways i tried calling it with `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'navbar'...%>`from application.html.erb and it didnt worked